# Duplicate Content and News - How do SE's treat them?

Tags: duplicate-content

I am planning to start a news website wherein I will be syndicating news from News Distribution Services and Press Releases. What most Webmasters in this field do is to directly copy (or atleast 95% of) the content provided by the news distribution service or press release and publish them. So, eventually, there are many news sites that are going to have the same content (or with a very few changes) and it happens that some of these sites have a PR of 6 or even 7 or 8. Obviously, they rank higher. In my website, I will have a news section which will essentially contain the content from the PR or NDS but I will also have more sections wherein I will be posting High Quality and Original articles. How would Google and other Search Engines treat my website for duplicate content.

P.S. I definitely wan't the news section because I wan't my readers to get access to news as well. Can spinning news articles be a good Idea? What I wan't to do is grab the news source and write it in my own words and then publish it. Please post suggestions.

Comment: Are you paying a licensing fee for the reuse of this information? The original news source owns the copyright for their information, so any reuse on your part may be subjected to future litigation. I would recommend checking your sources for their guidelines on the reuse of their information to ensure that they allow it.

Comment: I have checked the terms and conditions and it states that a linkback to the sources is the only requirement.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If your are just grabbing a news feed and publishing it verbatim, as so many other sites do, then you are effectively a news scrapper and your pages will not perform favorably on google. However, if you rewrite into your own wording using the feed as a reference then you will find that you can do very well indeed - even outstripping higher PR sites if you are fresher and faster. Though don't be too persnickety. You can quote parts of another document within your own text without penalty.